# How to fix map is not function even there is already set data in the useState using React Hook

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

Right now I am creating a chart and the chart data is based on the backend api created. Now I have problem where I need to push all the amounts in the array. So by doing this I need of course map the state and push it on the array however there is error happen it says that
***TypeError: receiveGroupCount.map is not a function***. I don't know why this happen.

**Error:**

[image: Error]

**Response:**

[image: response]

**State:**

```
const [receiveCheckCount, setReceiveCheckCount] = useState();

const [receiveGroupCount, setReceiveGroupCount] = useState({
});
```

**API:**

```
        let list_filter_countings_url = process.env.BASEURL+"chart_filter_range/"+moment(selectionRange.startDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD")+"/"+moment(selectionRange.endDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
        axios.get(list_filter_countings_url, { headers: { 'Authorization': AuthToken, 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } })
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            if(res) {
                const count_receive_check = res.data.data.receive;
                const count_receive_grouped = res.data.data.data_receive_grouped;
                setReceiveCheckCount(count_receive_check);
                setReceiveGroupCount(count_receive_grouped);
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
        });
```

**Chart Parameters:**

```
useEffect(() => {
    setChartData({
        labels: dataDate(selectionRange),
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'Receive Check',
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(195 218 251 / 35%)',
                borderColor: '#70a8f3',
                pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
                pointBorderWidth: '2',
                fill: true,
                lineTension: 0.0,
                pointRadius: 7,
                borderWidth: 1,
                data: randomVal(),
                //data:[12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3]
            }
        ]
    })
},[selectionRange,receiveGroupCount,receiveCheckCount])

const randomVal = () => { 
    
    var randomArr = []
    var from = new Date(selectionRange.startDate);
    var to = new Date(selectionRange.endDate);

    console.log(receiveGroupCount)

    if(receiveGroupCount != null) {
        for (var day = from; day <= to; day.setDate(day.getDate() + 1)) {
            receiveGroupCount.map((rows) => {
                randomArr.push(rows.amount)
            })
        }  
        return randomArr
    }
}
```

Comment: please check before iterate map receiveGroupCount is empty or not

Comment: use this one `const [receiveGroupCount, setReceiveGroupCount] = useState([]);`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're initializing that state to an empty object:

`const [receiveGroupCount, setReceiveGroupCount] = useState({});`

Objects don't have a `.map` property. Try initializing to an empty array instead.

Answer (score 0):

receiveGroupCount is not `null` initially, it is `{}`(an empty object) because of this statement:
`const [receiveGroupCount, setReceiveGroupCount] = useState({ });`

`.map()` is a method for arrays, and although you might have an array like data later in receiveGroupCount, the first time your `randomVal()` is run, it will fail.

You are already trying to mitigate the issue by checking for `null` but if you do not want to change your initial state you can change your if check like this:

```
if(receiveGroupCount != {}) {
        for (var day = from; day <= to; day.setDate(day.getDate() + 1)) {
            receiveGroupCount.map((rows) => {
                randomArr.push(rows.amount)
            })
        }  
        return randomArr
    }
```

Note: Your `useEffect` will run the first time and after every render where any of the `selectionRange,receiveGroupCount,receiveCheckCount` changes.

Comment: what should need to do to fix on it?

Comment: What is console.log(receiveGroupCount) printing after changing code like above.

Comment: Also, please add to the question where you are making the API call.

Comment: I try other suggestion I replace {} to [] it works.

Answer (score 0):

You just simply have to create a state with the default variable
try:

```
const [receiveGroupCount, setReceiveGroupCount] = useState({
        labels: // your code here,
        datasets: []
    });
```